# facebook-share popup not getting customized for an Iframe application created with DotNet Libraries

Tags: facebook

0  vote down  star

I have a .aspx page and I am creating a Facebook iframe applcation and i want to implement the share functionality on my page by using which the facebook user is able to share the contents of my page on his/her wall I using the following code to achieve this functionality

```
function fbs_click() 
{
       u="http://apps.facebook.com/shareddatas/default.aspx/";

       t=document.title; 
       alert(u);
       window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
       return false;
}
```

-->

**

My problem is if in the javascript function fbs_click() if i use u = "http://www"DOT"google"DOT"com" then the google image and google customized content is coming properly but if i assign the value of u = "MYaPP@FACEBOOK" then i just get apps"DOT"facebook"DOT"com on my share.php popup and what ever customized content i want to share across doesn't appear on that

Is there is a way of customizing the share.php for iframe application if not then by what means can i achieve the functionality of sharing the contents available on my page on to my wall

Answer (score 1):

The whole methodology for sharing/liking has changed.  I would suggest you convert over to using the new Like Plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/